# Reality of "electrical explosion"

Tags: electricity

I have often heard people who have been electrocuted refer to the "explosion" and how they were "thrown back" by the "blast". Sometimes the force of the blast is reported to throw people many metres.

There is no *explosive* involved - how can there be a repulsive force from a discharge of electricity?

Comment: With some luck the cramping of muscles will pull/throw a person away from the electric circuit. Unfortunately that is not always the case. There are loud arc discharges when power networks are shorted and there is a flash, maybe some observers identify that with an "explosion", but unless the accident happens on a major power line, the total energy release does not qualify for the term "explosion". In any case, one should not take accidents with power lines lightly, not even with 115/230V lines at home.

Comment: This is my assumption, that the motive force that people say they experience is actually all coming from their own muscles. However, one story I heard involved a major power line and the victim was physically lifted and thrown much further then his own strength would permit. My tendency is to believe this is embellishment of the story but wondered if there is any possibility it might be a real phenomenon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arc flash is a separate issue from electrocution.  It has only been integrated fully into the electrical codes over the last decade, and is not well recognized by folks not up to date on the latest requirements.

Arc flash is now covered well in the various electrical code documents. A rapidly expanding plasma generated by high voltages and currents rapidly releases very large amounts of energy. Yes, the result can look like a bomb went off, and be fatal to anyone within the arc flash approach boundary.

Think of 100s of volts with 100s of amps initiating an arc between two conductors. The copper starts to vaporize. The currents ionize the air and molten metal, allowing more current to flow. The air rapidly heats up and expands supersonically in a giant glowing plasma ball. As it turns out people die mainly from the blunt force trauma of the event, next by inhalation of superheated air with molten metal. Yes, they are blown backwards by the impact. A very nasty event.

Answer (score 2):

CuriousOne's comments basically answered your question.  I will add that if enough current is allowed to suddenly flow it can vaporize materials very rapidly, including metal.  This sudden vaporization can create a rapid expansion and if that expansion is restricted by something then it can explode in the same fashion as a bomb.  You often hear of transformers being "blown" because the high current inside causes it to rapidly expand faster than the pressure can be relieved, thus blowing up the container.

Comment: Good point - I could see that vaporisation in a restricted space would create an explosion. None of the examples I've heard involved any kind of restriction at all though. I wonder if the vaporisation could be **so fast** that it does cause expansion at a rate similar to a chemical explosion?

Comment: @Lefty Do you have a specific example you can describe in detail?  Anecdotal stories that get retold are often not accurate.

Comment: They are purely anecdotes so no point in recounting them in a scientific forum like this. However, in all cases they were told to me by someone who had no particular need to exaggerate - other than the normal social ones you could imagine.

Comment: Arc flash is a well known safety issue, covered well in the various electrical code documents.  A rapidly expanding plasma generated by high voltages and currents rapidly releases very large amounts of energy. Yes, the result can look like a bimb went off, and be fatal to anyone within the arc flash approach boundary.

Comment: A "bimb"..? Are you Inspector Clouseau? :) @Jon, could you expand on the mechanism a little in an answer please? You say it can **look** like a bomb but does it _behave_ like a bomb in that it could blast people backwards?

Comment: Think of 100s of volts with 100s of amps initiating an arc between two conductors.  The copper starts to vaporize. The currents ionize the air and molten metal, allowing more current to flow.  The air rapidly heats up and expands supersonically in a giant glowing plasma ball. As it turns out people die mainly from the blunt force trauma of the event, next by inhalation of superheated air with molten metal.  Yes, they are blown backwards by the impact.  A very nasty event.

Comment: @Jon That's amazing. I've read the Wiki page on Arc flash and it verifies what you are saying. So, it really does seem that electricity can cause an explosion with no help other than the copper conductors. From what I can see, it can happen at the sort of voltages/currents that are experienced in homes and businesses too, not just high tension cables. I'd be very happy to mark this as an answer if you were to submit it.

Comment: @Lefty arc flashes are due to the ionization of air (affects are identical to the vaporization of solids or liquids).  These are pretty uncommon because you need very high voltage 10's to 1000's of kilovolts of potential for a significant effect.  Otherwise you just get the spark like you see on an arc welder.  Essentially it is all the same effect, rapid heating and expansion.  Without more detail on your "explosions" we can't really help explain much further than that.

Answer (score 1):

The "explosion" is actually a physiological response of the body of the person electrocuted.

Our muscles are basically commanded by electrical signals through the nerves to expand and contract.

When large currents flow in the body from an electric shock (in the form of ion currents), these flows "hijack" the muscles, and the latter "thinks" they are being commanded to contract.

Uninhibited by conscious control, your body's muscles are, for fleeting periods, far more powerful than you would otherwise believe. A violent contraction from an electric shock could easily throw the body a considerable distance.

The effect may be two way. Just as the brain controls the muscles by electrical impulses, so too do the latter communicate their state to the former by the same. This is how we have sensations. So a large, foreign, current could well induce a preception of havoc or "explosion" in the brain of the shocked person.

EDIT in answer to user Lefty's comment:

> I don't buy this answer. Why would a general current through the body cause muscles that conveniently push the victim AWAY from the source of the shock. If the current causes muscle contractions then why wouldn't it cause a form of "rigor mortis" in which all muscles contract together. I know for sure that when I shocked my own hand, I wasn't able to move my hand away from the conductor in either direction but had to use my shoulder to pull the arm away. Also, I don't believe there's a great deal of real evidence in this "superhuman strength" idea. Evolution doesn't give us muscles that are 10 times stronger than they need to be and then never gives us the ability to consciously - or unconsciously - bring it to bear when it's needed.

1. It doesn't happen like this all the time. Indeed, one of the great dangers of electricity is where the shock victim's muscles cause them to involuntarily grasp the high potential conductor, thus causing a huge, sustained, fatal current through the conductor. Gruesome finds of half burnt bodies wrapped around high tension conductors by line workers was commonplace when many citizens tried to steal electricity by attaching unmetered lines to the supply in Tbilisi after the USA power company AES lost their bill payments through corruption in the corporation itself and refused to acknowledge payment as discussed in the 2003 documentary ["Power Trip" by Paul Devlin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Trip_(film)). This uncontrollable grip effect is in keeping with your own observations;
2. Evolution does indeed give us the ability to for very high strength over very fleeting time intervals. This is enhanced even further by the [fight-or-flight response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fight-or-flight_response#Reaction) and results from highly unusual energy source metabolism by the muscles, particularly glycogen or fat. The fight-flight response aside, in a proper bench press setup to measure thrust of your thigh muscles, you may be surprised at the forces that they can exert over short time intervals. It is indeed exactly of the order of 10 times your weight;
3. The perception of explosion is probably very important here: the stimulus of the nervous system by foreign currents can lead to who knows what sensory perceptions by the brain. I recall as a child accidentally reading in a news magazine the account of perceptions by someone who survived the electric chair - from memory it was consistent with my point but I can't give you a reference because I categorically DO NOT have the stomach to risk reading this account again if I go seeking it, but it should be readily enough found. I do not have to warn you that this is a ***thoroughly harrowing thing to read***;
4. Ohmic losses through an unintended short through living tissue across a very high tension, low source impedance sources does indeed result in an explosion. A tree branch, particularly a green one, yields a neighbourhood-shaking detonation if it falls across the phases of power lines in the street (22kV between phases here in Australia). This arises simply from the swift expansion of water and liquids in the branch as its ionic pathways conduct between the phases. Someone truly exploding off a short like this may very well not be around to give an account.

Comment: I don't buy this answer. Why would a general current through the body cause muscles that conveniently push the victim AWAY from the source of the shock. If the current causes muscle contractions then why wouldn't it cause a form of "rigor mortis" in which all muscles contract together. I know for sure that when I shocked my own hand, I wasn't able to move my hand away from the conductor in either direction but had to use my _shoulder_ to pull the arm away. Also, I don't believe there's a great deal of real evidence in this "superhuman strength" idea. Evolution doesn't give us muscles that are

Comment: ...10 times stronger than they need to be and then never gives us the ability to consciously - or unconsciously - bring it to bear when it's needed.

Comment: @Lefty: see my edits

Comment: 1. This seems to confirm my thinking, that the shock would not appear like a blast due to the physiological response. 2. Yes, I know we can push with force larger than our weight, but we can't leap 5 metres from a standing start. If we could, I contend that evolution would have given us that ability to escape danger. 3. I'm not talking about the perception of the _victim_ but that of _onlookers_ who (allegedly) see people blasted away. 4. The blast of a tree branch is a somewhat different thing caused by boiling of water in a confined environment so I don't think that relates to this at all.